# How can I concatenate an array in jade?

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to concatenate the items in an array `c[x].topLevelIndustry`  by using a for loop:

```
 -var text="";
 -var y;
 script.
   for (y=0, y< c[x].topLevelIndustry.length, y++){
     text+=#{c[x].topLevelIndustry[y]} + ",";
   }
 p= text
```

1. How can this be fixed, I've tried multiple things?
2. What is the relation between variables in jade/javascript? If I set `-var somevar` then how do I make it available for jade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the script tag prevents pug from running the code. Instead, it's passed on to the browser to execute client-side. Instead of a script tag, use an [unbuffered code block](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code).

```
-
  var text = "";
  var y;
  for (y = 0, y < c[x].topLevelIndustry.length, y++){
    text += c[x].topLevelIndustry[y] + ",";
  }

p #{text}
```

The same result can be achieved more concisely using the [`.join()` javascript method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
p= c[x].topLevelIndustry.join()
```